# Any possible alternate method to use static variable in multi threading

Tags: multithreading, static

I am in a suitation where i have to use static variable for multiple threads. Is there is any alternate methods which can work for the same. Kindly ignores ridiculousness.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Threads are also functions fundamentally.
So static variable will have same behavior in terms of threads as how it works with normal fucntions.

Because static variable stores in a section of process other than the stack segment , any change in static variable in one thread will reflect in another thread.